# How to convert output of HttpClient's PostAsJsonAsync() into user defined list of object

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am making of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class to call an end point. This endpoint is expect certain input and returns a List of user defined object of type `Employee ( List<Employee>)`.

This is the code that I am using.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7792/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                FilterModel payload = new FilterModel();
                payload.employeeId= 97050001;
                payload.Level= "Manager";


                // New code:
                HttpResponseMessage response =  client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/employee", payload).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var employee=  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//HOW DO I CONVERT THE OUTPUT INTO LIST<EMPLOYEE>?

                    Console.Write("---DONE---");

                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

I know this is not the ideal way to call an end point & I must use asyc await. I just need the data, the call can be sync or async & I want to type cast the result into List.

Currently I get a string back which I need to deserialize. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JsonConvert as below:

```
var jsonString=  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonString);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2020:
Use some thing like this:

```
return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Employee>>();
```